# How can you train GATE (General Architecture for Text Enginnering) Developer with some training data or data that already annotated?

Tags: nlp, gate

I am looking for ways to train my GATE. Not just running the application, but training it with like data that already annotated (not just plain document). I really appreciate if anybody help me. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm really not an expert about GATE, but what I understand is that it's a framework which controls work flows and such. What one typically wants to train are the models of components like taggers and other classifiers; these are tools that are part of a work flow. There might be tools that allow retraining from within GATE, but I wouldn't know of any. I guess most of them are black-box components plugged into GATE without the possibility to update the models.

Comment: Somebody else might be able to help you if you specify what tools you specifically want to train.

Comment: https://github.com/GateNLP/gateplugin-LearningFramework